# how to know the name of the class belonging an attritube

Tags: java

Let punt be the next variable

```
Point punt = p.point
```

where p is an object od the Class A.
how to know the name of the class of the attribute p.point (i.e I need some sentence that prints A)?

Comment: Did you try to search this question online?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you just want to know the type of the object referenced by `punt` or do you want to know if its value came from a field of some class?

Answer (score 3):

```
p.point.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

**UPDATE**

or

```
p.point.getClass().getCanonicalName()
```

to get the *canonical name*, i.e. the [fully qualified name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name), of the type of the field *point* of a class *A*, with *p* being an instance of this class *A*.

Now if you want to get the simple name, i.e. "A", of the class *A* whose *p* is an instance of, then:

```
p.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Other possibility, you want to know the name of the class A from inside the class A itself:

- with java < 1.7, only a static reference is available, i.e.: `A.class.getSimpleName()`
- since java 1.7, using reflection API: `MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getSimpleName()`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to obtain the name of class *A*, then you can use the next expression:

```
p.getClass().getName()
```

If you need to obtain the name of the class *A* **from inside the object punt**, then you can't. The object *punt* can be an attribute of the class *A*, and an attribute of many other different class too, at the same time. You can´t know what class an object is inside. You need to access directly to the object *p*. Let me explain with an example:

```
public class Point {
    ....
    public String toString() {
        // from here, it's impossible to know what class is this object inside
    }
}    

public class A {
    public Point point;
}

public class B {
    public Point anotherPoint;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    A p = new A();
    B q = new B();

    p.point = new Point();
    q.point = p.point; // shared reference here!!
    ....
    Point punt = p.point; // p is an attribute of A and B at the same time!!
    System.out.println(p.getClass().getName()); // direct access to the "p" object
}
```